# Eiffel: How to get class of a Void object? is it possible?

Tags: eiffel

I have a void object which I declared, but want to get its class name is it possible??

```
item: detachable DB_ENTITY

db_connection.base_selection.query("SELECT * FROM " + item.generating_type.out)
```

Creating it is not what I want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A type object (i.e. an object like the one returned by `generating_type` for an existing object) can be obtained using curly braces enclosing the type name:

```
    {MY_TYPE}
```

In your example it would be `{attached like item}` if `item` is a feature (of type `detachable DB_ENTITY` to allow for a value `Void`), or `{DB_ENTITY}` if `item` is a local variable, so that the whole expression would read in one of the following ways:

```
  db_connection.base_selection.query("SELECT * FROM " + ({attached like item}).out)
  db_connection.base_selection.query("SELECT * FROM " + ({DB_ENTITY}).out)
```

In the second case, the corresponding string would be equivalent to `"SELECT * FROM DB_ENTITY"`.

Comment: Thx, your first answer was the one, could you explain why you added attached to 'like item'?

Comment: @PhilippeGachoud If the feature `item` is of type `DB_ENTITY`, this type is attached, and `like item` is attached as well. However, if you want to allow `item` to be `Void`, you need to declare it as `detachable DB_ENTITY`. In that case `like item` is detachable. To be attached, it should be written as `attached like item`.

Comment: I'll read more about the topic... https://www.eiffel.org/doc/eiffel/Void-safety-_Background%2C_definition%2C_and_tools

Comment: Actually, ({attached like item}).out gave me `!COMPANY` not `COMPANY` why that? because its a created object isn't it?? so got to find another workaround

Comment: @Pipo I guess `like item` without any attachment mark will do.

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
item_type_anchor: detachable DB_ENTITY
          -- `item_type_anchor' for Current.
```

and then

```
db_connection.base_selection.query ("SELECT * FROM " + ({like item_type_anchor}).generating_type.out)
```

This means that the feature `item_type_anchor' clearly communicates that it does not expect to be attached, but is there as a type-anchor reference only. Used with the static reference Alex pointed out, the story is now clear and concise. :-)

Comment: The expression `({like item_type_anchor}).generating_type` computes a type of a type object, i.e. `TYPE [TYPE [DB_ENTITY]]`. And the subsequent call to `out` will yield a string `"TYPE [DB_ENTITY]"` that is not what is needed.